# Plastic permittivity compared to vacuum permittivity?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, electrostatics, physical-constants

I'm studying electromagnetism and I have found that vacuum permittivity is equal to:
\begin{equation}
   8.854 × 10^{-12}  C m^{-1} V^{-1} 
\end{equation}
and the relative permittivity of plastic is almost $2.39$
(this is an approximate value that I've found in an experiment)

and I want to know:

1- why the value of vacuum permittivity is too small compared to the relative permittivity of plastic?

2- why I have found this large value ($2.39$), in other words why there's some dielectrics that have large values of their relative permittivity while others have small values?

3- is this a good value for the relative permittivity of plastic ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value for plastic likely assume vacuum permittivity of 1

Comment: Is that supposed to be the *relative* permittivity of plastic, or did you mean to include units there?

Comment: @Sandejo yes exactlly the relative permittivity of plastic

Comment: @JonCuster I really didn't get your point

Comment: @LEARNER $2.39$ is the relative permittivity, which is the ratio $\epsilon / \epsilon_0$.

Comment: @user7777777 yes!

Answer (score 0):

The electric field from a free point charge is:

$$ |{\bf E}| = \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{|q_f|}{r^2}$$

so the permittivity regulates the strength of the field emanating from a charge (inversely).

If you replace the vacuum with a dielectric, the material polarizes, thereby partially screening the charge. The field is reduced for $\epsilon > \epsilon_0$:

$$ |{\bf E}| = \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon} \frac{|q_f|}{r^2}$$

To bookkeep and keep Maxwell's, you add the apparent charge from the divergence of the polarization:

$$ \rho = \rho_f - \nabla \cdot {\bf P}$$

and define the displacement field:

$$ {\bf D} = \epsilon {\bf E}$$

so that:

$$ |{\bf D}| = \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{|q_f|}{r^2}$$